# Find the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty}(a^x+b^x-c^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Let a>b>c>0.

How may one find the limit $\lim_{x \to \infty} (a^x+b^x-c^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}$?

It's obvious that it's bounded from below by c, so I tried to show that it's also bounded from above by c and then use sandwich (I factored out c and then tried to show that the limit is 1).

I also tried to use the method of $e^{ln}$, but also got nowhere... L'Hospital also didn't help.

Please help, thank you!

Comment: So you are saying that you transformed the limit to $\lim_{x\to\infty}c\left(\left(\frac ac\right)^x+\left(\frac bc\right)^x-1\right)^\frac 1x$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. How may I continue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have been given $a\gt b\gt c\gt 0$.  Then

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} (a^x+b^x-c^x)^{\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x \to \infty} a\left(1+\left(\frac ba\right)^x-\left(\frac ca\right)^x\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

$$=a\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1+\frac {b^x-c^x}{a^x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\le a\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1+\frac {b^x}{a^x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}$$

We have $a\gt b$ therefore $\forall x\gt 0, \frac {b^x}{a^x}\le 1$.  So

$$a\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1+\frac {b^x}{a^x}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}\le a\lim_{x \to \infty} (1+1)^{\frac{1}{x}}=a\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[x]{2}=a$$

To squeeze the limit from the other side, simply note that since $b\gt c$ then $\frac{b^x-c^x}{a^x}\gt0$ and so the limit is greater than the $x$th root of $1+0$ times $a$ which is also $a$.

Answer (score 1):

$L = \lim_{x\to \infty} a(1+(\frac{b}{a})^x-(\frac{c}{a})^x)^\frac{1}{x}$. Can you do it now? Note that $a>b>c>0$.